# Password Strength Implementation ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I was looking at password strength implementations with ExtJS and came across this particular implementation,

[A password strength meter for passwords for ExtJS4.](http://www.simoens.org/Ext.plugin.extjs.form.PasswordStrength/)

This is implemented using ExtJS 4 and i was looking to use it with ExtJS 3.
I tried a few options, but couldn't figure out much.

Please let me know if there is something specific i need to do in order to get it working with ExtJS 3.

Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.plugin.extjs.form.PasswordStrength/blob/master/Ext.plugin.extjs.form.PasswordStrength.js) for this plugin if that would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In several my projects I used this widget:
[Ext.ux.PasswordMeter](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?12155-0.2-Ext.ux.PasswordMeter)

It worked well, so I think you can review it too.

Comment: The link was dead and i had to email the creator and got the link back up. Used it in my project now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why dead? Checked just now, works well: [alive link](http://testcases.pagebakers.com/PasswordMeter/).

Comment: Like i said, "I had to email the creator to get the link working again.". The link wasn't working.

Comment: Good, thanks. I've added a comment just for future readers, so they can be sure it works now :)

Answer (score 4):

Seems easy enough. All you would do is extend the `Ext.form.TextField` class with that same logic. They are processing the actual 'strength' with the `onFieldChange` event, which in Ext 3 doesn't exist from what I can see in the docs, but you could easily do the same with the `keyup : ( Ext.form.TextField this, Ext.EventObject e )` event.

Take a look at the source and see that they define 2 functions, `processValue` and `scorePassword`. You could copy those functions directly, and then implement the keyup function to use those.

You would create the class:

```
    Ext.form.PasswordStrength = Ext.extend(Ext.form.TextField, {


        initComponent: function () {

           // write your code, functions, etc here

            // default values you want for your TextField
            var config = {

            }

            Ext.apply(this, config);

            Ext.form.PasswordStrength.superclass.initComponent(this);

        }
    });

   // register an xtype
    Ext.reg("passwordstrength", Ext.form.PasswordStrength);
```

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall give it a spin tomorrow and let you know how it goes :)

Answer (score 2):

I modified the Ext.ux.PasswordMeter to be Ext JS 4 compatible. Here is the code: [my blog](http://yiyujia.blogspot.com/2011/09/ext-js-4-password-meter-widget.html)

please feel free to give me feedback.